# formatting dictionary values

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

I am needing to store values in a dictionary in the following format:

```
{ "UserId": 123,
  "UserType": "blue", 
    "UserActs": [{
           "ActId": 3,
           "Time": 1
       }, {
           "ActId": 1,
           "Time": 6
       }]
    }
```

I know I'll need a dictionary for the intitial values and a nested one for the UserActs but I am unsure how to store seperate values for the same keys "ActId" and "Time".  How would I go about adding them in the dictionary following this format?

Comment: That is JSON.  Use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the old, long winded, way of creating that dictionary (there is a new syntax, using Objective-C literals, however they are not mutable, so I chose this method):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:123] forKey:@"UserId"];
[dict setObject:@"blue" forKey:@"UserType"];

NSMutableArray *acts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[acts addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], @"ActId",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"Time",
    nil]];
[acts addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"ActId",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:6], @"Time",
    nil]];
[dict setObject:acts forKey:@"UserActs"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the shorthand for arrays and dictionaries

```
NSDictionary * dictionary = @{ @"UserId": @123,
  @"UserType": @"blue", 
    @"UserActs": @[@{
           @"ActId": @3,
           @"Time": @1
       }, @{
           @"ActId": @1,
           @"Time": @6
       }]
    };
```

Comment: `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:3`] == `@3`, making it even shorter!

Comment: It wasn't from me.  I got one too; at roughly the same time, so I assume it was the same person downvoting both of us.